# PHP quote within 2 different quotes

Tags: php, quote

I have a problem with quotes. I can't use " or ' for $gname. What can I do for this.

`$new_post = array( 'post_content' => ' ..CODES.. $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wp_games WHERE name = $gname "); ..CODES..`

I'm trying to create a post on wordpress.I have a plugin to use php on posts. [insert_php] is this plugin. And I also can't use quote like \" ... \" .Here is more code.

```
$new_post = array(
'post_content' => '[insert_php]$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wordpress");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wp_games WHERE name = '$gname' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo $row["name"];
}

mysqli_close($con);
[/insert_php]',
```

Comment: That is broken on so many levels - very messy and prone to rampant PHP and/or SQL injection. In any case, see [PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for how quotes can be escaped in a PHP-string context. (Where, like a bad remake of Inception, the inner string literal is two levels deep..)

Comment: Post your actual code, I don't help to answer pseudos, it just keeps us guessing till the cows come home.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, "I have a plugin to use php on posts" <- please don't do that, either; it sounds like a recipe for disaster. Wordpress has enough security holes of its own without making it even easier to `eval()` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single quote using `chr(39)` and append it to the string. You should also escape the contents of `$gname`

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM wp_games WHERE name = " . chr(39) . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $gname) . chr(39));
```

Comment: The problem is there is a single quote after post_content and a double quote in mysqli_query. So I can't use any quote for $gname.

Comment: @NaimBerkTumer I updated my code with a workaround to get single quotes into the string without using the single-quote character.